# Blender 2.8 camera how to rotate vertically

Tags: rendering, camera

I would like to position the camera to render this pillar along its vertical axis as I indicated in the red square.

I have searched around but could not find anything to help me.  This problem is recurring quite a lot lately.  It is possible to rotate the camera vertically? If yes how please?  Thanks.[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can rotate the camera along its local z axis. Pres Z, Z, R and rotate by 90°. But sometimes its easier to simply change output aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks can you please tell me how to change the aspect ratio.

Comment: Simple :). Instead of 1920x1080 you flip the values.

Comment: Noob in the matter here.  Can you please tell me where to do it.  Ty

Comment: Sure :). In the [dimensions panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html) flip X ad Y values. I can't post a full answer now, sorry.